# I can't serialize a list of tabular java tables using GSON

Tags: java, gson, tabula

I use Tabula (java) to extract tables contained in pdf files. After obtaining a list of tables I use the Gson class to realize this list. However, the following exception is thrown.

***Table extraction and serelization***

```
List<Table> tables = new PDFTableExtractor(document).extract(page);
new Gson().toJson(tables);
```

***Exception thrown***

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdk.internal.ref.PhantomCleanable<?> declares multiple JSON fields named next
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
```

I'm using the Table class from the Tabula library. The class contains the following attributes:

```
private final String extractionMethod;
private int rowCount = 0; 
private int colCount = 0; 
private List<List<RectangularTextContainer>> memoizedRows = null; 
/* visible for testing */ final TreeMap<CellPosition, RectangularTextContainer> cells = new TreeMap<>();
```

Comment: What does the data look like?  What fields are in the `Table` class?

Comment: I'm using the Table class from the tabular library. The class contains the following attributes: `private final String extractionMethod;
private int rowCount = 0;
private int colCount = 0;
private List<List<RectangularTextContainer>> memoizedRows = null;
/* visible for testing */ final TreeMap<CellPosition, RectangularTextContainer> cells = new TreeMap<>();`

Comment: I would open an issue with the library.  It may not be very easy to serialize.

Comment: Please [edit] and update the question with details rather than in comment.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(maintainer of `tabula-java` here)

The library already implements serialization with Gson. Take a look at [`TableSerializer`](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/blob/master/src/main/java/technology/tabula/json/TableSerializer.java)